# Strange values when adding members in member function

Tags: c++, class

I made two constructors in Vector class.

```cpp
public:
    Vector() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
    Vector(int _x, int _y, int _z) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }
```

and I created an Add function inside the Vector class.
This function will add two vectors.

```cpp
    Vector Add(Vector v) {
        Vector output;
        output.x = x + v.x;
        output.y = y + v.y;
        output.z = z + v.z;
        return output;
    }
```

In the main function, I would like to add `vectorA(1, 2, 3)` and `VectorB(4, 5, 6)` to get the value of `vectorO(5, 7, 9)`.

```cpp
int main()
{
    Vector vectorA(1, 2, 3);
    Vector vectorB(4, 5, 6);
    Vector vectorO = vectorA.Add(vectorB);

    printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", vectorO.x, vectorO.y, vectorO.z); // (5, 7, 9)


    return 0;
}
```

However, only abnormal values are printed, such as (0, 1075052544, 0).
There is no error message, is there a solution?

I don't think it's the constructor's problem, should I fix the main function?

Edit point

I cut off the code to make it readable.
However, the code lacked information, so I put the entire code in it.

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

class Vector
{
public: // private?
    double x, y, z;

public:
    Vector() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
    Vector(int _x, int _y, int _z) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }
    double Magnitude(void);

    Vector Add(Vector v) {
        Vector output;
        output.x = x + v.x;
        output.y = y + v.y;
        output.z = z + v.z;
        return output;
    }

    Vector Subract(Vector v);
    double DotProduct(Vector v);
    Vector CrossProduct(Vector v);
};

int main()
{
    Vector vectorA(1, 2, 3);
    Vector vectorB(4, 5, 6);
    Vector vectorO = vectorA.Add(vectorB);

    printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", vectorO.x, vectorO.y, vectorO.z); // (5, 7, 9)


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What are the types of `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: I`m sorry. I have edit it.

Comment: You are telling `printf` that you want to display integers when you use `%d`, you need to tell it you want to display doubles instead.

Comment: You don't need to write so much code in `Add`. `return Vector(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z);` is fine.

Comment: `printf` strikes again. Have you considered using `std::cout << vectorO.x << vectorO.y << vectorO.z;` instead? You don't have to remember magic codes and it will (almost) always print what you want.